# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'cmul'

Tags: pytorch

I was trying to do element-wise multiplication of two tensors using the example provided [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#res-torchcmulres-tensor1-tensor2).

My code:

```
import torch

x = torch.Tensor([2, 3])
y = torch.Tensor([2, 1])
z = torch.cmul(x, y)
print(z)
```

It is giving me the following error.

```
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'cmul'
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Instead of using `cmul`, I need to use `mul`. The following code worked for me!

```
import torch

x = torch.Tensor([2, 3])
y = torch.Tensor([2, 1])
z = torch.mul(x, y)
print(z)
```

PS: I was using pytorch, not lua.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
z = x.cmul(y)
```

I think `cmul` is a method of the class `Tensor`, not a function...

PS: The exemple in the documentation you gave is written in lua, not python.

Answer (score 0):

Because Torch doesnt have this method.
Cmul is a class on its own which is located at `torch.legacy.nn` which takes Torch as arguments
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/legacy/nn/CMul.py